# Native Command Error GPG Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption, error-handling, gnupg

We are using GPG to encrypt/decrypt files. This gpg is being called in a powershell as follows

```
 gpg -o $myOfile -d $myDfile
                      #Check if decryption succeeded
                        If($?)
                        {
                          Echo "`nDecryption of $myDfile succeeded"
                          Echo "Decrypted file is $myOfile`n"
```

When we run the script, the decryption is taking place correctly. After the decryption is done, the script fails with the below error

> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (gpg: Signature ...key ID XXXXXXX:String) [], RemoteException
>
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I looked up answers for a few other questions with similar answer but none of the suggestions are working. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Sree

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same issue.

Comment: The answer mentioned below worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$?` is not used for the console apps, but for Powershell cmdlets. Try with

```
if (!$LastExitCode) {

}
```